# Can't edit old post

Tags: support, title

I've got a question called [subset sum problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125795/subset-sum-problem), which is the proper name of the problem. Now I want to edit the question and I can't edit it, because the system will reject the title for having "problem" in the name. Subset Sum Problem is the *proper name* of the task at hand, not some generic "Problem with C++" title. How can I edit my question?

Edit: I admit, it was a bad title to begin with. However, that had nothing to do with the reason the system rejected it, which was because it has "problem" in the title. If I were to extend it by saying "subset sum problem algorithm in polynomial time?" it would still have been rejected.

Comment: Word-based filtering is stupid. Stupid. Stupid.

Comment: @sbi an epidemic of bad titles is far stupider.

Comment: @Jeff: You cannot prevent bad titles by filtering for words. You killing Martinho's answer proving this doesn't change that fact.

Answer (score -4):

Your title

> subset sum problem

Is .. not very good to start with. I changed it to

> Is my subset sum algorithm in polynomial time?

Which I feel does a far better job of accurately describing the actual content of your question.

Comment: I'm just a furriner, but "Is my subset sum algorithm in polynomial time?" makes me doubt it's even proper English.

Comment: Admittedly, it isn't good to begin with. However, that has nothing to do with the fact that it has "problem" in it.